# Nutch 2 parse and outlinks

Tags: nutch

I've noticed that parse plugins like tika extract the outlinks from the content, but the object WebPage passed in method getParse/2 already have 2 arrays containing outlinks and inlinks.

Whats the difference between the extraction in getParse and after fetch.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Webpage object is created from the information in nutch database, in my case hsql.

The Webpage field outlinks(and some others) is filled after the parse process (after method getParse returns).